# Javascript reverse device detection

Tags: mobile, browser-detection

I'm using the code from detectmobilebrowsers to redirect mobile users to an optimized page. However, if they copy that url and send it to a desktop user, it won't look right.

So... I want to reverse the code on the mobile page to say if NOT (one of these mobile devices) redirect to desktop page. I just can't figure out where the exclamation goes.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any relevant code you could post? That will help you get a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was being lazy, and not reading where the regex started. Here's what I was looking for:
    (function(a,b){if(!(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile...more stuff here... |zte-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))))window.location=b})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://myRedirect.com');